# JavaScript Function Sequence

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to JavaScript and I wondered if someone can help with a question re function sequence. As I understand functions are executed in the sequence they are called, so I don't understand why in the example below mySecond() is executed although it is called after myFirst()? Thanks

```js
function myDisplayer(some) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some;
}

function myFirst() {
  myDisplayer("Hello");
}

function mySecond() {
  myDisplayer("Goodbye");
}

myFirst();
mySecond();
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Function Sequence</h2>
<p>JavaScript functions are executed in the sequence they are called.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What makes you think that is happening?

Comment: They're both executed, in order, and that means the demo paragraph ends up with the second value.

Comment: Both functions are running, the first one runs, and then the second one runs, overwriting that contents that was set by the first function.

Comment: ^ Note though that with `alert` this may be even more confusing because the browser won't necessarily render the changed contents before the alert is shown, since it's technically still inside the JavaScript execution operation. A `setTimeout` would make it clearer but I presume the OP didn't learn about callbacks yet.

Comment: Put a console.log in your function and watch your dev tool, you will see it's running in the correct order. Please DON'T use alert., guarantee you will regret it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I didn't realise that I was replacing and not appending to the contents (I must have missed it) but after updating my code I can see that both functions are running and all makes sense now. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

It is exactly as you said, they are executed in order:

- `myFirst()` runs and changes the contents of the `demo` element from empty to `Hello`.
- `mySecond()` runs and changes the contents of the `demo` element from `Hello` to `Goodbye`.

End result: Contents of the `demo` element are `Goodbye`.

You can try something else like *appending* to the contents instead of replacing them, or using `console.log` to add log entries to the console, to see more clearly what happens. You can also use the devtools to debug your code and single-step through each line that executes.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use console.log to see what happens

```js
function myDisplayer(some) {
  console.log(some);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some;
}

function myFirst() {
  myDisplayer("Hello");
}

function mySecond() {
  myDisplayer("Goodbye");
}

myFirst();
mySecond();
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Function Sequence</h2>
<p>JavaScript functions are executed in the sequence they are called.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're both executed, you may rewrite myDisplayer so you can see both results

```
function myDisplayer(some) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += some;
}
```